# How to safely close form soon after it's shown?

Tags: c#, winforms

From my main form, I open a couple of other forms on mouseclick, like so:

Main Form:

```
...
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    frmNewForm newForm = frmNewForm();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

In the new form, I'd like to check if there's any data to show, and if not immediately close the form.
New Form:

```
...
public frmNewForm(){
    InitializeComponent();

    // check if opening this form makes sense
    if(noData){
        Close();
    }
}
```

However, I get an exception thrown at `frmNewForm.Show()`: The object can't be accessed.

I apologize if the translation isn't exactly the same as Visual Studio's: I'm working with another language version.

Anyway, what can I do to safely close `frmNewForm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to do it in the constructor for the new form. Rather, you need to do it on the `Load` event so that it finishes loading before you close it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (noData) this.Close();
    }
```

Alternatively, if you know you won't need to open the form, check before showing it!

Answer (score 2):

If `noData` is a public Boolean property of your `frmNewForm` class, you can do this:

```
if( !newForm.noData )
{
     newForm.Show();
}
```

Make sense?

Comment: This is more efficent than yamen answer because the memory allocation `(InitializeComponent();)` will not take place if there is no data.

Comment: I don't think that is entirely correct. `InitializeComponent();` is called in the constructor, so it's already happened before we do our "no data" check. We should save on the resources that would have been allocated to actually draw the window, though.

Comment: Yeah i missed that newForm object is already created. we are calling if condition afterwards. Sorry my mistake.